# Expanding a div over another div on hover with transitions

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I have divs styled as columns

```
[div1][div2][div3]
```

I want to expand each div individually on a cursor hover like so (overlaying the other divs somehow):

```
[div1..................]
```

I've got it working like this thus far: https://codepen.io/Cigoler/pen/VMZeaB

```css
body {
  background: #cacaca;
  padding: 5em;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  padding: 0.25em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.test1 {
  background: #c3c3c3;
}

.test2 {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.test3 {
  background: #474747;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row expanded">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item test1">
      <p>Test One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item test2">
      <p>Test Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item test3">
      <p>Test Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is; I want to take it further and smoothly animate the transition. However it becomes janky whenever I add even a simple transition. I'm guessing it's because the browser is fighting between the divs in-between the animations.

Any help for solving this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try making the `div.item` position absolute by default.Then on hover change the width and left position of the div

A sample

```css
body {
  background: #cacaca;
  padding: 5em;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  padding: 0.25em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
}
.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  z-index: 999;
}

.test1 {
  background: #c3c3c3;
  left: 0px;
}

.test2 {
  background: #fafafa;
  left: 33%;
}

.test3 {
  background: #474747;
  color: white;
  left: 66%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row expanded">
<div class="container">
  <div class="item test1">
    <p>Test One</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item test2">
    <p>Test Two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item test3">
    <p>Test Three</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one is better than the other upvoted answer. So, voted up ;)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of *positioning* you can use a CSS3 solution based on `flexbox` -

1. Add `display: flex` to the `container`
2. Add `min-width: 0` to the `item` and `flex: 1 1 0%` which set the `flexbox` to *grow* and *shrink* as it seems fit and set a `flex-basis` of zero.
3. Add `flex-basis: 100%` to `item:hover` and remove *absolute positioning*

See demo below:

```css
body {
  background: #cacaca;
  padding: 5em;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex; /* ADDED */
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 0%; /* ADDED */
  min-width: 0; /* ADDED */
  /*padding: 0.25em;*/
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  height: 200px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*left: 0;*/
  flex-basis: 100%; /* ADDED */
  -webkit-transition: flex-basis 0.3s ease-out; /* MODIFIED */
  transition: flex-basis 0.3s ease-out; /* MODIFIED */
}

.test1 {
  background: #c3c3c3;
}

.test2 {
  background: #fafafa;
}

.test3 {
  background: #474747;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row expanded">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item test1">
      <p>Test One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item test2">
      <p>Test Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item test3">
      <p>Test Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did consider flexbox but I was worried about browser support - it's definitely a nice solution though.